# Does the LG Aristo work with gamepads, if so how can I connect it too the ípega?

Tags: lg, game-controllers

I have an LG Aristo and I recently got an ípega Bluetooth controller off the wish website, the phone isn't rooted an I don't know much on what to do so it's not working for any of my games I don't know what to do please help...

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your GamePad to your LG as you connect  headphones or any wireless devices.

Your gamepad  supports android 3.2 and above.

**METHOD 1:**

- Install `iPega Game Center English version`(Google for that).  and install it. This will serve as  IPEGA remote Bluetooth gamepad driver for your Android device.
- Enable Bluetooth on your LG phone.
- Once you have installed the IPEGA Game Center successully you need to enable BitGames IME as default input.
- Turn on the controller by pressing Y + Home button simultaneously. Wait until the red LED indicator blinks as it pairs with your device.
- Once the red LED indicator blinks, open the IPEGA Game Center application. Go to ***mydevice*** and ***bind controller***.
- A console will open. This will help you calibrate your controller.  Try moving the joystick and the buttons.
- Done. Test it with a supported game or an emulator.

**METHOD 2:**

If you have the PG-9028 model, you won't need  the IPEGA Bluetooth controller app.

- Turn on your IPEGA PG-9028. Also, make sure that your LG Bluetooth is turned on.
- Now, on your IPEGA Bluetooth controller,  press and hold both the X + HOME button, simultaneously.
- Wait until you see the LED from your IPEGA gamepad with touchpad blinking constantly.
- On your mobile device,  open the Bluetooth menu. Scroll down (if needed) and look for Available Devices.
- What you should look for is “PG-9028” or sometimes Android will see it as a keyboard input device.
- Select PG-9028 to start pairing. Once the pairing is successful, you will notice that the LED light on your IPEGA PG-9028 will stop blinking.
- Done.