# LG Aristo 2 and Xbox 360 Controller with USB OTG

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I'd like to connect my phone (LG Aristo 2) to an Xbox 360 controller. It is wired, and I've connected it to my phone via USB OTG. It doesn't function currently; no button presses make any action. Is there a way to get this controller working with this phone via USB?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be of any help? I suppose connecting it to an Xbox controller would work if you can use any other controller.
[Does the LG Aristo work with gamepads, if so how can I connect it too the ípega?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/176103)